# Using multiple commands on a single line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have these three commands - how do i execute them on a single line?

```
@echo off
echo SomeText
pause
```

Not one after to other like it normally is in batch.

Comment: What do you actually expect to happen? What problem are you trying to solve? How would it help to "run the three commands at the same time"?

Comment: It would help the code be more compact.

Comment: What would that help? Using shortcuts like that is usually frowned upon, since it hurts readability. However, in your case, you could get away with `@echo SomeText & pause`. In any case, you should edit your question. You're not asking how to run the commands at the same time - you're asking how to put the commands at the same *line* in the batch file. A very different thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try linking them with a "&"

```
@echo off & echo SomeText & pause
```

It works in most cases but more complicated code with "()" in may cause problems as the brackets will need escaping.